# Conditional Projection with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm not able to get the following query to work. The grouping and total sum works without problem, but when I try to do the conditional sum, I receive the following error on the compiler:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NHibernate.Criterion.IProjection' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ManagementWebBase.Models.FinancialTransaction.FinancialTransactionTO, object>>'
```

The code of the function is:

```
var summary = session.QueryOver<FinancialTransactionTO>().Select(
            Projections.Group<FinancialTransactionTO>(t=>t.Company.Id),
            Projections.Sum<FinancialTransactionTO>(t=>t.Total),
            Projections.Sum<FinancialTransactionTO>(
            Projections.Conditional(
            Restrictions.Where<FinancialTransactionTO>(f => f.Type.Id == 1),
            Projections.Constant(1),
            Projections.Constant(0)))).List<object>();

        return summary;
```

All the examples i've seen have no differences. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Solved using Projection.Sum without the Type on the conditional part:
Here is the working example I'm using:

```
var summary = session.QueryOver<FinancialTransactionTO>().Select(
            Projections.Group<FinancialTransactionTO>(t => t.Company.Id),
            Projections.Sum<FinancialTransactionTO>(t => t.Total),
            Projections.Sum(
            Projections.Conditional(
            Restrictions.Where<FinancialTransactionTO>(f => f.Type.Id == 1),
            Projections.Property<FinancialTransactionTO>(f=>f.Total),
            Projections.Constant(0.0M, NHibernateUtil.Decimal)))).List<object>();

        return summary;
```